# BATCH - String manipulation

Tags: string, batch-file

I need help in splitting text in a document call date_baseline.txt
The contents of this file is :

```
1st Day = 2011-08-26
2nd Day = 2011-07-30
3rd Day = 2011-07-29
```

I need to take out each of the date's shown above. Any pros with batch knowledge?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!

`for /f "tokens=3 delims== " %i in (date_baseline.txt) do @echo %i`

If you want to put that into a batch file,

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=3 delims== " %%i in (date_baseline.txt) do (
    echo %%i
)
```

Note that just extracting the last fragment, `3` is sufficient.

Comment: is there a way to take them out and put each of those dates into a variable?

Answer (score 1):

If by "take out", you mean "extract", the following would be a good start:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=4" %%a in (input.txt) do (
    call :process %%a
)
endlocal
goto :eof

:process
    set myvar=%1
    echo !myvar!
    goto :eof
```

This outputs:

```
2011-08-26
2011-07-30
2011-07-29
```

The `process` function can be modified to do whatever you wish. At the moment, it simply save it in a variable and then prints that but you can do arbitrarily complex processing on it.

Comment: i would like to store it into a variable. may i know how? :)

Comment: @user866800, assuming you want to do something with each date, I've put in a call to a function. Whatever you want to do with the dates can be put in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vbscript` ,

```
Set objFS=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFile = "c:\test\file"
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfLine
    strLine= objFile.ReadLine
    s = Split(strLine,"=")
    WScript.Echo s(1) 'display the date column
Loop
objFile.Close
```